# Is doing service calls inside DBIO.from within a Slick transaction a good idea?

Tags: database, scala, transactions, slick

Our project uses Slick and is split into modules where every module has a service layer (business logic, depends on other services potentially in different modules) which may encapsulate a couple of DAO layers which return `DBIO` actions.

We're composing those `DBIO` actions from different `DAO`s on the service layer to run business logic within transactions.

The question is simple, when a service `A` depends on service `B` and needs to call a function from service `B`, should we put that call to `B` within `DBIO.from` or first do the service call to `B` and then based on the result execute the DB transaction.

Benefits of making a call to service `B` within `DBIO.from` is that if the call fails our transaction rollbacks, but of course if it succeeds and then something fails we're basically in the same situation as not doing the call from `DBIO.from`.

Drawback is that as far as I'm aware DB transactions should be short and quick and doing a call to an external service within a DB transaction sounds like a bad idea ("code smell").

What's your opinion?

Comment: Can you illustrate with some code sample ?